# Right way to make a real time countdown timer in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to develop a timetable app. I have TableViewController which shows the classes on current day. How can I achieve cell - which shows the current class - with countdown timer?

I tried with an NSTimer which calls tableView.reloadData() every second but I think it's not a good way, and I have a continuous 2-3% CPU usage.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJtiC.png) screenshot shows how I imagine it. (Biology class should have a timer, third cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reload the whole table. The timer and the update of the controls should happen within the table view cell subclass, not within the encompassing controller.

Don't forget to dismiss your timer when your cell receives the `- (void)prepareForReuse` message, though, or you'll run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot. I have another problem with this ViewController. Would you mind checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028318/tableview-section-update-depend-on-coredata-transient-property-change) question?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to create a timer is this:

- When the timer starts, calculate the time it will finish. E.g. timer should run an hour, now it's 8:28 so it'll be done at 9:28. Save the finishing time
- Every time you update your display, calculate the time remaining between now and the saved time and update your label with it. Like this you can update every label at the same time

Answer (score -1):

1. add UILabel to your cell
2. get how long the class is for example 60 mins
3. start NSTimer get called every second or min as you like and run it.
4. start the label with the highest number the total time of the class 60:00.
5. if the timer working in seconds with every 60 time the timer get called get the mins field by - one (you can covert the string into 2 object of type NSNumber to be able to work with).
6. and every time the min field get - one start the second field over with 59.
7. every time the timer get called get the second field - one
8. make sure you have condition when the fields reach zeros the label right done.

you can use reloadData every time or reloadCell

hope this answer can help you good luck